# JavaFX8 TableView with custom control

Tags: java, custom-controls, tableview, javafx-8

I want to use a custom control (ClientControl in the code) in my TableView. Therefore I created a class ClientCell:

```
    public class NewClientCell extends TableCell<Client, Client> {
    private final ClientControl cc;

    public NewClientCell(ObservableList<Client> suggestions) {
        cc = new ClientControl(this.getItem(), suggestions);
        this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        this.setGraphic(cc);
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    }
@Override
protected void updateItem(Client c, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(c, empty);
    if(!empty){
        setGraphic(cc);
    }
}
}
```

In the main program I use the following code to fill the table:

```
        TableColumn<Client, Client> clmClients = new TableColumn<>("Klient");
    clmClients.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Client, Client>, TableCell<Client, Client>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Client, Client> call(TableColumn<Client, Client> p) {
            return new NewClientCell(suggestions);
        };
    });

    clmClients.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Client, Client>, ObservableValue<Client>>() { 
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Client> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Client, Client> p) {
            return new SimpleObjectProperty<Client>(p.getValue());
        }
    });
    getColumns().add(clmClients);
```

The data in the table comes from an ObservableList and is initialized correct.

My problem now is that the custom control needs an Client-Object which it should get out of the ObservableList, but "this.getItem()" always returns null.

How do I get the Client objects correctly into the custom control?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's the constructor of ClientControl:

```
    public ClientControl(Client client, ObservableList<Client> suggestions) {
    setClient(client);
    setSuggestions(suggestions);
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ClientControl.fxml"));
    loader.setRoot(this);
    loader.setController(this);
    try {
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    initTextField();
    setLabelText(client.toString());
}
```

The method setClient is a simple setter method (this.client = client;). The variables client and suggestions are this simple defined:

```
    private ObservableList<Client> suggestions;
private Client client;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you should instantiate any controls in the constructor as you did, so that they are only created once (remember that cells get reused for different locations).

But then you need to override one or more of the other methods such as `updateItem` to get the data from the current item to render.

**EDIT**

Well, you're assigning the same control without changing it over and over again. Rather than setting the graphics in the updateItem method, set the item property of the client control:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Client c, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(c, empty);
    if(!empty){
        cc.setClient(c);
    } else {
        cc.setClient(null);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

The ClientControl should provide the client item as a property instead of a constructor argument and set it in the updateItem method, not in the constructor.

E.g. something like this (untested!):

```
private final ObjectProperty<Client> client = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "client");
public final Client getClient(){
    return clientProperty().get();
}
public final void setClient(Client client){
    clientProperty().set(client);
}

public ObjectProperty<Client> clientProperty(){
    return client;
}
```

And in the constructor: listen for changes of this property to set the labelText etc.
You also might want to provide a constructor without a client argument, as it is not available when you instantiate it in the TableCell constructor.

Comment: The updateItem method calls the setGraphic method like in another custom cell I use, but here it doesn't work.

Comment: @SaschaProschinger Your NewClientCell class only defines a constructor not the updateItem method....!?

Comment: Sorry, I meant I added the updateItem method like I did in another controls. See edited question.

Comment: Well, this is an important piece of information. See my updated answer.

Comment: I updated the updateItem method this way but it didn't help. After some tests I see that at the initialisation the ClientCell doesn't get any Client, so "this.getItem()" returns null. But there are many Clients in the list.

Comment: The ClientControl should take the item as a property and be set in the updateItem method, not in the constructor. Please update your code in the question and also show us the relevant part of the ClientControl (constructor, item property etc.).

Comment: You're still setting the client in the constructor not via the property then?

Comment: Changed my code before I saw your edit, but solved the problem. You see the detailed solution in my answer below. I would like to upvote your answer, but I haven't enough reputation :-(

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution for my problem. Thank you so much Puce for your help! :-)
Now I set Client via the property like that:

```
    private ObjectProperty<Client> clientProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<Client>();
```

Additionally I added a ChangeListener in the constructor of ClientControl:

```
    public ClientControl(ObservableList<Client> suggestions) {
    clientProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Client>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Client> observable, Client oldValue,
                ClientnewValue) {
            if(newValue != null) {
                setLabelText(newValue.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    setSuggestions(suggestions);
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ClientControl.fxml"));
    loader.setRoot(this);
    loader.setController(this);
    try {
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    initTextField();
}
```

My ClientCell class needed only some simple changes because of the changes in ClientControl:

```
public class NewClientCell extends TableCell<Client, Client> {
private final ClientControl cc;

public NewClientCell(ObservableList<Client> suggestions) {
    cc = new ClientControl(suggestions);
this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
this.setGraphic(cc);
this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
}

@Override
protected void updateItem(Client c, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(c, empty);
    if(!empty){
        cc.setClient(c);
    }
}
}
```

In the main program nothing changed.

In conclusion I would like to thank Puce one more time, I stuck at this problem for many days...

Comment: Use `new ChangeListener<Client>` instead of `new ChangeListener<Object>` and then you can use the `newValue` argument directly instead of `clientProperty.get()`.

Comment: I suggest to follow the naming conventions I mentioned... (only the metod returning the JavaFX property object is called clientProperty).

Comment: And remove the line `cc.setClientProperty(this.getItem());` from the constructor of NewClientCell as the item is null anyway.

Comment: In the updateItem method you're doing the same thing in the if and else clause...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the code in the answer too (was only a quick 'n' dirty solution)